# Hyperlink Reference to another column DevExpress Gridview ASP.Net Webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms, devexpress

I'm using a for loop to add columns to the DevExpress ASP.Net WebForms GridView  using VB.Net. I was able to get a hyperlink to reference the same column value:

```
Dim newColumn As New DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn
newColumn.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.NavigateUrlFormatString = "TrendView.aspx?CurrentID={0}"
```

I need to programmatically set the hyperlink to another column's value... i.e. column three needs to have a hyperlink that references the column 1 value in the same row. How do you access another column in that row using VB or C# during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this url to solve your problem

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E308

change your populate grid logic as

**ASPX :**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**CS**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName = "ID";
     ASPxGridView1.DataSource = GetData();
     if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
     {
         PopulateColumns();
         ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
     }
}

public DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable Table = new DataTable();
    Table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    Table.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
    Table.Columns.Add("ItemValue", typeof(string));
    Table.Rows.Add(1, "A","AA");
    Table.Rows.Add(2, "B","BB");
    return Table;
}

public void PopulateColumns()
{
    GridViewDataTextColumn colID = new GridViewDataTextColumn();
    colID.FieldName = "ID";
    ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(colID);

    GridViewDataTextColumn srk = new GridViewDataTextColumn();
    srk.FieldName = "ItemValue";
    ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(srk);

    GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn colItemName = new GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn();
    colItemName.FieldName = "ItemValue";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.NavigateUrlFormatString = "~/details.aspx?Device={0}";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.TextFormatString = "{0}";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.TextField = "ItemName";
    ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(colItemName);
}
```

here column itemName refer to itemValue as url string params

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not sure how that solves my problem. I believe that the example just formats the cell's current value. If column 0 row 0 has the string "value1", and column 3 row 0 has the string "value2", how would I format the column 3 url to include the column 0 value. In this example column 3 row 0 would have the link: "~/details.aspx?Device=value1".

Comment: i have changed my code as per your need i hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show hyperlink text based on multiple columns then HyperlinkColumn is not the right approach to implement. It would be better use templates.

You should create `DataItemTemplate` for the column and there you can use `Bind` statement to format the display text or Hyperlink url as you want. It is the same approach used in ASP.NET GridView control and work in similar manner with ASPxGridView control.

I suggest you to go through these example and attached sample projects will help you know about the implementation.

[ASPxGridView - How to customize HyperLink column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q307866)
[How to use a hyperlink whose argument depends on several cell values in the ASPxGridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E993)
[How to customize navigate URL for HyperLink column within a ASPxGridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q519734) - This contains sample attached in the answer.

**Example:** DataItemTemplate for column.

```
            <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ContactName" VisibleIndex="3">
                <DataItemTemplate>
                    <dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
                        TextField="ContactName" ValueField="ContactName" Value='<%#Bind("ContactName")%>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="ASPxComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="onSelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </dxe:ASPxComboBox>
                </DataItemTemplate>
            </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

or

```
<dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="ASPxHyperLink3" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/AccountDetail.aspx?CategoryID={0}", Eval("i_Customer")) %>'
    Text='<%# string.Format("i_Customer{0}", Eval("i_Customer")) %>' .../>
```

[ASPxGridView - ASPxHyperLink Navigate URL formatting](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q300402)
[ASPxGridView - How to set GridViewDataHyperlinkColumn's text and navigate url](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q457589)