# ASP.Net DevExpress Gridview exporter CSV download with hyperlink link to website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I'm using **[DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/)** Gridview exporter  **to export Gridview to CSV** and I wanted the `sno` field name's row data to become hyperlink and when I click on that it will show webpage of

```
https://xxx?sno_id
```

The CSV is exported with hyperlink on `sno` field name but I have no idea on how to make it works as what I wanted.

I have referred to this [site](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q555935/aspxgridview-export-excel-with-hyperlink-field-issue), but still the same outcome.

**ASP.net**

```
<dx:ASPxGridViewExporter GridViewID="FeedbackGrid" ID="exportFeedbackGrid" onrenderbrick="exportFeedbackGrid_RenderBrick" runat="server"> 
</dx:ASPxGridViewExporter>

     <dx:ASPxGridView ID="FeedbackGrid" ClientIDMode="Static" OnCustomUnboundColumnData="FeedbackGrid_CustomUnboundColumnData" ClientInstanceName="FeedbackGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <Columns>
               <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn FieldName="sno" Visible="false" PropertiesHyperLinkEdit-NavigateUrlFormatString="Http://{0}">                                
               </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>
          </Columns></dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**Vb.net**

```
  Protected Sub FeedbackGridBut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        FeedbackGrid.Columns("sno").Visible = True
        exportFeedbackGrid.WriteXlsToResponse()

  End Sub

  Protected Sub ExportFeedbackGrid_RenderBrick(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewExportRenderingEventArgs) Handles exportFeedbackGrid.RenderBrick

      Dim dataColumn As GridViewDataColumn = e.Column As GridViewDataColumn 
        If Not e.RowType = GridViewRowType.Data And dataColumn Is Nothing Then
        e.TextValue = e.Value.ToString()
    End If

 End Sub
```

anyone has idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display something else on column value but it will create hyperlink with sno column. I suggest you to check the below reference:
[Hyperlink Reference to another column DevExpress Gridview ASP.Net Webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234825/hyperlink-reference-to-another-column-devexpress-gridview-asp-net-webform?rq=1)

e.g.

```
GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn colItemName = new GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn();
    colItemName.FieldName = "sno";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.NavigateUrlFormatString = "~/details.aspx?Device={0}";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.TextFormatString = "{0}";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.TextField = "AnotherColumnFieldName";
    ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(colItemName);
```

References:
[ASPxGridView - How to customize HyperLink column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q307866/aspxgridview-how-to-customize-hyperlink-column)
[How to create and configure a HyperLink column at runtime](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-create-and-configure-a-hyperlink-column-at-runtime-e308)

If does not help then provide more details about the required functionality.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have solved it with this method. <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn FieldName="sno" Visible="false" Settings-AllowEllipsisInText="True" PropertiesHyperLinkEdit-NavigateUrlFormatString="Http://xx.aspx?sno={0}">                                
                                    </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>